# jQuery autocomplete select event and blur event on input field relation

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, onblur

I have a question about the jQuery UI Autocomplete component. I initialize the component in the following way:

```
var $input = $('#autocompleteInput');
$input.autocomplete({
    source: source,
    appendTo: appendToSelector,
    select: function(event, ui) {
       console.log('select');
    },
    minLength: 0
});

//...

$input.on('blur', function(e) {
  console.log('blur');
});
```

When I try this code in the browser and select an item from the autocomplete dropdown list, I always see `selected` printed before `blur` in the Chrome console:

> selected
>
> blur

Can I be sure that these two listeners are always executed in this order (selected first and blur after) when I select an item from the autocomplete? How can I be sure that the order of execution will be always this?

Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Are you asking for Chrome only or for all browsers? Is there a specific scenario you're looking to encounter or avoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question in short, no. There are a number of scenarios that can result in many different combinations.

Here is some testing:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/b4nyguqd/

**HTML**

```
<div>
  <label>Search:</label>
  <input id="autocompleteInput" type="text" />
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="eventLog">
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
function upEvent(log) {
  var d = new Date();
  var time = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes() + ":" + d.getSeconds();
  $("#eventLog").append("<p>" + time + " - " + log + "</p>\r\n");
}
$(function() {
  var source = [
    "ActionScript",
    "AppleScript",
    "Asp",
    "BASIC",
    "C",
    "C++",
    "Clojure",
    "COBOL",
    "ColdFusion",
    "Erlang",
    "Fortran",
    "Groovy",
    "Haskell",
    "Java",
    "JavaScript",
    "Lisp",
    "Perl",
    "PHP",
    "Python",
    "Ruby",
    "Scala",
    "Scheme"
  ];
  var $input = $('#autocompleteInput');
  var appendToSelector = "#someElem";
  $input.autocomplete({
    source: source,
    select: function(event, ui) {
      upEvent(event.type);
    },
    minLength: 0
  });

  $input.on('blur', function(e) {
    upEvent(e.type);
  });
});
```

As a user, I can only do a few things, but for example here are the first few I tested:

1. Type 'app', result shown: 'AppleScript'
2. Arrow down until 'AppleScript' is highlighted
3. Press Return key
4. Delete until only 'A' remains
5. Arrow down to 'ActionScript'
6. Press Return
7. Click the mouse on the page outside of text field

The results:

```
10:35:18 - autocompleteselect
10:35:24 - autocompleteselect
10:35:26 - blur
```

As you can see, I've performed normal operations, but `blur` was never triggered since I never lost focus of the test field.

**Update**

---

After your comment, you can see:

https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/b4nyguqd/2/

My results:

```
13:54:2 - Temp value updated: AppleScript
13:54:2 - autocompleteselect
13:54:6 - Temp Value during blur: AppleScript
13:54:6 - blur
13:54:14 - Temp value updated: Asp
13:54:14 - autocompleteselect
13:54:20 - Temp Value during blur: Asp
13:54:20 - blur
```

Another Test lacking select and also selecting different values without blur events:

```
13:56:16 - Temp Value during blur: undefined
13:56:16 - blur
13:56:22 - Temp value updated: C++
13:56:22 - autocompleteselect
13:56:23 - Temp Value during blur: C++
13:56:23 - blur
13:56:28 - Temp value updated: C
13:56:28 - autocompleteselect
13:56:32 - Temp value updated: C++
13:56:32 - autocompleteselect
13:56:34 - Temp Value during blur: C++
13:56:34 - blur
```

Comment: Sure, but look at the `autocompleteselect` event: it seems that whatever you do, if there's a selection from the autocomplete field, the `blur` event, if triggered, will always trigger **after** the last `autocompleteselect` event. The important thing to me is that whenever the user makes a selection (be it using arrow keys and `Enter` or selecting the item with a click, or even selecting it with arrow keys and then pressing `Tab`), if there's the possibility for a `blur` event to be triggered, it will always be triggered on the field with the updated value selected from the autocomplete list.

Comment: Can you confirm this behaviour? I mean, if for example I set a global variable inside the `select: function(event, ui) {}` event listener of the autocomplete field and I set it to the value the user has selected, I then need to reference this value inside the `blur` event listener. Therefore I need to be sure that when the `blur` event listener is executed, the value of this global variable is the new one which was just selected by the user from the autocomplete, no matter, how. I hope it makes sense. Let me know if you understood me, otherwise I can write some code :)

Comment: The `blur` event will always be triggered whenever the focus is taken away from the selected element. So, to your point, yes, if something is selected, and the focus changes, you would see `select` and then `blur`. You also have the scenario where nothing is selected, and `blur` is triggered.

Comment: `Another Test lacking select and also selecting different values without blur events` Yes, but as soon as a blur event is triggered you always end up with a `temp` variable having the last selected item by the user. This is what matters to me. And if look at your code and at the outputs, it seems to always be so. It doesn't matter to me how many times you select an item from the autocomplete, provided that when you blur the autocomplete value is always the last one typed/selected by the user.

Comment: @tonix, in your OP,m you said, 'Can I be sure that these two listeners are always executed in this order...', so I thought it was important. I am glad that it sounds like you have the answer you need.

Comment: Yeah, maybe I was not so clear in my original question. Anyway, thank you for your help!